# Convert to negative a number

Tags: r

In data like this:

```
data.frame (com = c("col1","em"), stock1 = c(2.6, 0), aim = c(0,3.10))
```

How is it possible to add a minus to all rows of row with com "em"

Example of expected result:

```
data.frame (com = c("col1","em"), stock1 = c(2.6, 0), aim = c(0,-3.10))
   com stock1  aim
1 col1    2.6  0.0
2   em    0.0 -3.1
```

Comment: If a row with 'em' already has a minus, should that be left alone?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ifelse`:

```
df1 <- data.frame (com = c("col1","em"), stock1 = c(2.6, 0), aim = c(0,3.10))

df1$aim <- ifelse(df1$com == "em", -df1$aim, df1$aim)

df1
   com stock1  aim
1 col1    2.6  0.0
2   em    0.0 -3.1
```

Comment: What if there is a value > 0 in the `stock1` column? And there might be more numeric cols than just two (but I am obviously just guessing here).

Answer (score 1):

How does this work?

```
xy <- data.frame (com = c("col1","em"), stock1 = c(2.6, 0), aim = c(0,3.10))

find.com <- -which(names(xy) == "com")
xy[xy$com == "em", find.com] <- -xy[xy$com == "em", find.com]
xy

   com stock1  aim
1 col1    2.6  0.0
2   em    0.0 -3.1
```

Comment: @RuiBarradas you are of course correct. This solution assumes all number are positive, which may not be the case.